# (org-use-fast-tag-selection (quote auto)) - breaks TAB Completion; non ASCII tag selection characters [\200]

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I posted this in org-mode ML. No responses there so far, so cross-posting it here too.

I have​  one ​ persistent tag​​  set with a key character like this:
 `'(org-tag-persistent-alist (quote (("a" . 97))))`

There are no file based `#+TAGS` in any of org files.

I also like to have access to all tags in all files, so I set this up:
`(org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t)`

Finally I'd like to have a fast selection splash screen:
`(org-use-fast-tag-selection (quote auto))`

Now the problems:

​1. ​Running `C-c-q` in an org file on a heading shows a fast selection splash window​. ​​​It shows all the tags from all the org files.​ The main problem is that  apart from `[a]` defined in `org-tag-persistent-alist` other characters are​  assigned​  for​   fast pick ​  randomly​  and​  are not only 'a-z',  but also  seemingly​  non-ASCII characters which are shown as:
- `[\200] tagname1`
- `[\204] tagname2`
- etc
There seems to be no way to select tagname1 or tagname2.

2. With all the above variables unchanged hitting the `TAB` here for selection of tags in the minibuffer only allows tags already in the file, ignoring the `(org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t)` variable. Disabling ​  `'​org-use-fast-tag-selection​'` by setting it​ to  'nil'​   and hitting `TAB` after `C-q` 
   produces `:` and the Completions buffer is not opened. However, typing a first character of a tag, say `b` and hitting `TAB` opens 'Completions' buffer and lists all tags starting with `b` ​.

Note that org ido completion (which would be shown as 'Ido Completions' buffer name) is not used (although  `(org-completion-use-ido t)`) if 
`(org-use-fast-tag-selection (quote ​  nil​  ))`​  .​

3. ​I​n addition to problem 1., and problem 2., `TAB` does not show a full list of tags in the Completions buffer​ which start with 'a' {probably due to the tag `a` ​ defined above}, but selecting another starting letter and hitting TAB opens Completion buffer with all tags starting with `b`​  .

So, fast select seems broken.

I would expect it behave like this:

1. Having `(org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t)` and `(org-use-fast-tag-selection (quote auto))` should limit the tags selection to ASCII only characters or offer double character selection like [aa]-[zz] if there are more tags that az permits. Use numbers perhaps too?.
2. If 1. is not possible then perhaps limit the characters to ​  '​a​-​z​'​   and leaving other tags out of the fast select but allow TAB to choose all tags in all org files using org-ido?

I'm forced currently to disable `(org-use-fast-tag-selection (quote auto))`  setting it to  `(org-use-fast-tag-selection (quote ​nil​))` and use the Completions buffer, which ​ seems to work more consistently.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  What version of Org mode are you using?  Are you able to isolate this behavior with a minimal configuration and minimal Org file using `emacs -Q`?  Also, are you rebinding `C-q` (was `quote insert`) to `org-set-tags-command` or do you mean `C-c C-q`?

Comment: version: `Org-mode version 8.2.10 (8.2.10-37-gc000e8-elpa @ /Users/xxxx/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150420/)`. Indeed, `C-c-q`. Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 24.4.91.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1265.21) of 2015-03-25`

Comment: just now tried `emacs -Q` in terminal. Then I set '(org-tag-persistent-alist (quote (("a" . 97))))` and `(org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t)`. Loaded a single simple org file with a single tag in it. Hitting `C-c-q` shows a persistent tag and the file tag. However, adding the whole org directory to agenda [with many tags in them already set], still produces the initial problem.

Comment: I assume the problem occurs if the number of tags in all org files is more than 26 ASCII letters, which is my case.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot may help. [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/pnTLr3c.png?1)

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce this.  As you suggest, the number of tags exceeds the keys.  Looking briefly at the source of `org-fast-tag-selection`, it seems like it just continues to bump the character.  I recommend you post to the mailing list again to discuss a fix for this.

Comment: 1.  This should be moved to Emacs.SE.  2.  Please share the link to the mailing list thread.

Comment: ML post was a year ago, I searched for it in my mailbox, could not find. The archive search in ML (Namazu) seems broken, or I can't figure out how to use it. Perhaps you will have a better luck.