# org-agenda-bulk-action B + tag selection does not offer completion

Tags: emacs, org-mode

org-agenda-bulk-action `B` `+` tag selection does not offer completion. I use `Ido completion`. The tag completion for individual agenda items works in org-agenda mode.

Disabling `Ido` does not help.

Any idea if bulk tag selection completion is implemented at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be partially implemented.  If you set `org-tag-alist`,
you'll be offered these tags when running the bulk action (after reloading the original Org buffers).  Unlike `org-set-tags`, `org-agenda-bulk-action` does not generate the tags based on the tags in the Org buffer if `org-tag-alist` is nil.  (At first glance, I don't see any reason why it couldn't be extended to do this.)

Comment: Thank you @Kyle Meyer. Can I ask you to have a look at my related question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535230/org-use-fast-tag-selection-quote-auto-breaks-tab-completion-non-ascii-tag). It explains the reasons I'm not using `org-tag-alist`.